# Ormlite exception on joined query

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm having a bit of trouble getting some OrmLite stuff to work - been using document databases a bit too long I think! Given I have the following models:

```
public class ListingEvent
{
    public ListingEvent()
    {

    }

    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id {
        get ;
        set;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Location))]
    public int LocationId {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Location 
{
    public Location()
    {
        ListingEvents = new List<ListingEvent>();
    }

    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id {
        get ;
        set;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<ListingEvent> ListingEvents { get;  set; }
}
```

And the following query:

```
var listingEvents = db.Select<ListingEventDto> (
                    db.From<Model.ListingEvent>()
                    .Join<Model.ListingEvent, Model.Location> ()
                    .Where<Model.ListingEvent> (le => locationIds.Contains (le.LocationId) && le.Name.Contains (request.Query))
                    .Or<Model.ListingEvent, Model.Location>((le, l) => l.Name.Contains(request.Query) == true)
                    .Limit (skip: request.Skip, rows: request.Take));
```

Why on earth (baring in mind I have tried every connotation of this!) am I getting this error:

```
error CodeInvalidOperationException message variable 'l' of type 'Model.Location' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the expression below, i.e. a method expression on a column from a joined table:

```
.Or<Model.ListingEvent, Model.Location>((le, l) => l.Name.Contains(request.Query))
```

This issue was resolved [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/d018bd3710d21e5744ba64a1cde538ffd1c8f113), available from v4.0.33+ that's been [published to MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).